# NodeJS <--> Dll : Howto handle callback triggered from C method call

Tags: node.js, dll, node-ffi

We’re currently trying to integrate a dll with NodeJS.
The dll is a message bus which triggering a callback (if registered) when receiving a new message on the bus.
The attached dll simulates this behavior: loop infinitely, and on each loop call a  C method with a callback.
Here is my test case:

```
var ref = require("ref");
var ffi = require('ffi');
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var voidPtr = ref.types.void;

// Expose the DLL to node JS
var apiLib = ffi.Library('../bin/dispatch', {
    // C method declaring the callback
    'dispatchRegisterCallback': [ 'int', ['pointer', 'int'] ],
    // C method which simply call dispatchRegisterCallback
    'dispatchCallCallback': [ 'int', []]
});

// Callback
var myCallbackPtr = ffi.Callback('void', ['string'], function (message) {
    console.log('callback: ' + message);
});

// Registering the callback on the C method, starts a loop and
// call the method that triggers the callback from the Dll each 1 second
// DOES NOT WORK
apiLib.dispatchRegisterCallback(myCallbackPtr, 1000);

// Make Node Loop
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("loop");
    // Triggering the callback from NodeJS : OK
    //apiLib.dispatchCallCallback();
}
, 100);
// Keep the callback pointer to avoid GC
process.on('exit', function() {
    myCallbackPtr
})
```

And here is the source code of the sample dll

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dispatch.h"
#include <iostream>

pfnCallback * g_pfnCallback = NULL;

void CALLBACK timerFn(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
       std::cout << "dispatch.dll, timerFn" << std::endl;
       if (g_pfnCallback != NULL)
       {
             std::cout << "dispatch.dll, timerFn : calling callback " << g_pfnCallback << std::endl;
             g_pfnCallback("callback call (timer)");
       }
}

/**
* Register a callback.
*/
int __stdcall dispatchRegisterCallback(pfnCallback fn, int interval)
{
       std::cout << "dispatch.dll, dispatchRegisterCallback" << std::endl;
       g_pfnCallback = fn;
       SetTimer(NULL, 0, interval, (TIMERPROC)timerFn);

       return true;
}

int __stdcall dispatchCallCallback()
{
       std::cout << "dispatch.dll, dispatchCallCallback" << std::endl;
       if (g_pfnCallback != NULL)
       {
             std::cout << "dispatch.dll, dispatchCallCallback : calling callback " << g_pfnCallback << std::endl;
             g_pfnCallback("callback call by dispatchCallCallback");
             return true;
       }
       return false;
}
```

Is it really possible with the FFI module ?
Should I use the Edge module instead, or maybe addons ?

Answer (score 1):

[SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) is a Windows function.

For it to work the application must have a Windows message loop:

> you need to dispatch messages in the calling thread, even when you use
>   TimerProc instead of processing WM_TIMER

But node.js uses IOCP on Windows. It does not dispatch messages.

One way to handle this is to use [uv_timer](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/timer.html) in your C++ code, but for this the dll will have to be linked to the node.exe (it exports the libuv functions as shared libraries do) using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp).

Note that this solution is cross-platform.

But the other method you already implemented using `setInterval` is easier and also cross-platform.

`setInterval` uses uv_timer under the hood.

Another solution is to create another thread in your native library and call the callback function from there. If you plan to use SetTimer then it must be called in the created thread and you will need a Windows message loop there.